# Cardinality of the stone Cech compactification of discrete topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, set-theory

Let $X$ be an infinite set equiped with the discrete topology. If $\beta(X)$ is the stone Cech compactification of $X,$ then is the relation $card(\beta(X))=2^{2^{card(I)}} $ holds?  (this claim is true for $X=\Bbb N.$)

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Indeed for a discrete space $X$, $\beta X$ is just the set of ultrafilters on $X$, and this has cardinality $2^{2^{|X|}}$ if $X$ is infinite.

For a proof of the latter statement, you can see one [here](https://planetmath.org/numberofultrafilters), or [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/independent+family+of+sets).

Comment: +1. There is a detailed presentation of the Wallmann Extension $wX$ of $X$ in General Topology by R. Engelking. If $X$ is a normal space then $wX$ is a maximal compactification of $X.$ In particular if $X$ is a discrete space then the set $wX$ is the set of ultrafilters on $X$ as you said.

Answer (score 0):

One standard way to construct $\beta(X)$ is to consider all continuous functions $f: X \to [0,1]$ (in fact any function on $X$ is continuous when $X$ is discrete); there are $|[0,1]^{|X|}| = 2^{|\aleph_0 \cdot X|} = 2^{|X|}$ many of those and the canonical Urysohn embedding $e_X$ maps $X$ into $[0,1]^{{2^|X|}}$ and $\beta(X)$ is the closure of $e_X[X]$, which thus has size at most $|[0,1]^{2^{|X|}}| = 2^{2^{|X|}}$, as required.